# UnityEvent with array showing null reference Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code snippet. Whats I am doing wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class UnityEventSystemDemo : MonoBehaviour {
    UnityEvent[] objUE;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        objUE = new UnityEvent[2];
        objUE[0].AddListener(CustomEvent);///Null ref at this point
        objUE[1].AddListener(CustomEvent);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Debug.Log("left clicked..");
            //calling Events
            objUE[0].Invoke();
            objUE[1].Invoke();
        }

    }

    void CustomEvent() {

        Debug.Log("customEvent..");

    }

    void CustomEvent1()
    {

        Debug.Log("customEvent1..");

    }
}
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object UnityEventSystemDemo.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/UnityEventSystemDemo.cs:23)

Comment: which line of code that error is? (no linenumbers here)

Comment: I have updated my code plz see

Comment: Just in case, if you are planning on iterating through the array to call all listeners, you can add many listeners into one instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialise the array Elements. Try updating you Start method like this.

```
objUE = new UnityEvent[2];
objUE[0] = new UnityEvent();
objUE[0].AddListener(CustomEvent);///Null ref at this point
objUE[1] = new UnityEvent();
objUE[1].AddListener(CustomEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marius Junak!